# Imageview not updating bitmap, android?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview

I have a viewpager of 4 pages, each viewpager page contains a recylerview. 
Recyclerview contains a list of 20-30 elements, in each element I have an imageView whose fuctionality is to download the file and replace it canvas bitmap showing downloaded percentage in a circular progress
.

I am downloading a file and showing progress with the help of canvas and updating the imageview.
Below is the code

radiusDifference is 7 for tablet and 5 for mobile screens.

```
private void circularImageBar(ImageView iv2, int progess, int radiusDifference) {
        System.out.println("sowload percent-" + progess);

            Bitmap b = null;
            Canvas canvas = null;
            Paint paint = null;
            if (b == null) {
                b = Bitmap.createBitmap(iv2.getWidth(), iv2.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                canvas = new Canvas(b);
                paint = new Paint();
            }

            paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(iv2.getWidth() / 10);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawCircle(iv2.getWidth() / 2, iv2.getHeight() / 2, 
                    (iv2.getWidth() / 2) - radiusDifference, paint);


            int tintColor = Color.parseColor("#F81004");
            paint.setColor(tintColor);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(iv2.getWidth() / 10);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            final RectF oval = new RectF();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            oval.set(radiusDifference, radiusDifference, iv2.getWidth() - radiusDifference, 
                    iv2.getHeight() - radiusDifference); 

            canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, ((progess * 360) / 100), false, paint);

            iv2.setImageBitmap(b);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                iv2.setForegroundGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            }
            iv2.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

The download is running and even the bitmap is created but it is not reflecting in UI.

Comment: Are you calling this method from a background thread or from the UIThread?

Comment: @MarcEstrada from UIThread

Comment: When is this method called? Are you sure your ImageView has a defined size when this method is called? Because if `iv2.getWitdh` and `iv2.getHeight` return `0` it'd explain why you don't see anything.

Comment: @Eselfar I have debugged for this and it returns me proper width and height

Comment: Can you please add the code where you call the method? I've tried your code and it works (at least it displays something). So if `iv2.getWidth` and `iv2.getHeight` are > 0 maybe your issue is that the `radiusDifference` value is too big?

Comment: @Eselfar i have updated the summary , please check the question again

Comment: Doesn't help much. As I said, this code works (not completely fine but it works, try mine below to see if it changes something), means the problem is either in you RecyclerView adapter or in the code that calls this method. So as long as you don't provide this code, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have added some improvements so now it's supposed to work no matter is the ImageView witdh and height.

```
private void circularImageBar(ImageView iv2, int progess, int radiusDifference) {
    System.out.println("sowload percent-" + progess);

    final int width = iv2.getWidth();
    final int height = iv2.getHeight();

    final Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);

    final int strokeWidth = width / 10;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    final int min = Math.min(width, height);
    final float radius = (min / 2f) - radiusDifference - (strokeWidth / 2f);
    final float cx = width / 2f;
    final float cy = height / 2f;

    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);

    final int tintColor = Color.parseColor("#F81004");
    paint.setColor(tintColor);
    final RectF oval = new RectF(cx - radius, cy - radius, cx + radius, cy + radius);

    canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, ((progess * 360) / 100f), false, paint);

    iv2.setImageBitmap(b);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        iv2.setForegroundGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    }
    iv2.requestLayout();
}
```